# Turkish kalem: from Anc. Greek or Tocharian?

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, greek, turkish, tocharian

Usually the Turkish word **kalem** *'pen'* is shown in etym. dictionaries to derive from Arabic *qalam*, which in turn derives from Greek **κάλαμος**. However, I noticed that Tocharian languages have the term **kalām** *'writing stylus'* and I started thinking of the possibility that the Turkish word is through earlier Turkic-Tocharian contacts and not a later Turkish-Arabic contact. Has anyone considered the Tocharian kalām?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Greek word kalamos “reed, reed pen, stylus” has a good Indo-European etymology (cognate with, for example, German Halm “reed”). It was borrowed not only in Arabic, as qalam, but also into Sanskrit as kalama-. The Tocharian word is presumably borrowed from Sanskrit. The Turkish word is from Arabic.

Comment: I don't doubt that it is IE. I just questioned if the source was definitively Arabic (from Greek) or if there was a possibility of the word passing into Turkic languages through Tocharian. Could we say it is out of the question?

Comment: I am hesitant to say that anything is completely out of the question. But since this word does not (as far as I can see) occur in Old Turkish it is certainly most likely that it is borrowed from Arabic.

Comment: what is the evidence that the arabs got it from the greeks?  obviously phonological similarity is not enough.  it would not be surprising if thevgreeks got it fron the arabs.

Comment: or if they both got it from the same ancient semitic root, separately.

Comment: @mobileink. The IE proto-form has been reconstructed as *ḱ(o)lh2-m-. It is not Semitic.

Comment: @fdb: thx. but (fwiw i am *extremely* skeptical of western attempts to trace arabice stuff to greek) even if scholars think they have a PIE derivation, that is something very different than saying "therefore it must have come from that."  it does not exclude parallel dev.  i would still likecto see posirive evidence that it came from greek inot arabic.  ansent that, it is just as reasonable to think it did not

Comment: @mobileink. This has nothing to do with "Western attempts". The existence of loan words even in the language of the Qur'an is recognised by classical Islamic scholars like as-Suyuti, al-Jawaliqi etc., etc.

Comment: @fdb: of course. all languages borrow. arabic borrowed copiously, which the arabs always frankly acknowleded. but the west has a long and sordid history of denigrating arabic/islamic thought as merely derivative. that's why i'm skeptical.  and you did not answer my question: where is the evidence? not saying it is not there, just want to see it.

Comment: @mobileink: It is always good to be skeptical towards PIE reconstructions that are based on a couple of attestations. I am in agreement with you about that. However, in this case the word is present in a number of languages, which leaves the burden of proof to the "Semitic side". In IE you have aside from the Greek and Tocharian words: Germanic halm, Balto-Slavic salme, Slavic solóma, Latin calamus and Sanskrit kaláma. You see that the phonological rules follow accordingly, they are not loans.

Comment: @Midas. IE *ḱ(o)lh2-m- accounts for the Greek, Balto-Slavic and Germanic forms. Latin calamus and Skt kalama- are borrowings from Greek; in genuine Skt words *ḱ would have become s-.

Comment: @fdb: That is correct and I was actually thinking of it. Kalama cannot be Sanskrit as the initial PIE *k would result something similar to the Baltic & Slavic forms. I also forgot to add Hittite kal-ma-ra- 'ray' and maybe kalmi 'type of firewood'.

Comment: @Midas: fwiw i poked around in the Chicago Assyrian Dictionary and could not find anthing promising.  If it were semitic i would expect to find sth there, so i'll go with the proposal that Arabic indeed borrowed it.

Comment: Of course, Germanic *halm* could conceivably be a pre-Grimm's Law loanword, like *hemp*.

Comment: @TKR. Of course.